# Batch Zonal Statistics to Spreadsheets?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, excel, ms-access, zonal-statistics

I have a pretty immense amount of Zonal Statistics as Table computations to do, and would love to find a way to grab mean and variance values from the little .dbf tables ArcGIS creates and put them neatly in spreadsheets.

I'm trying to get basic descriptive statistics on ~40 species distributions across about 6 climate scenarios, so it adds up pretty quickly.

I am a Python neophyte at best, so I don't know that I would be able to come up with satisfactory script to do this, though I have messed around with it some.

Can any of you think of another way to do this that would hopefully save a huge amount of time?  At this point I'm pretty much cutting and pasting values into a spreadsheet, which could well take me until my 80th birthday.

Other ideas: Access + pivot tables?  Trying to run the stats in R instead?

Anyway, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If I have time later this week I would like to try and work on this with you.
However, to lead you in the right direction you might want to look into search cursors, you can specify the fields and parse them to a text file or excel spreadsheet

Comment: Last time I looked Excel still supported VBA; it's not a big deal to open a dbf, get the values you want based on row & column and copy to another spreadsheet then repeat until all done. You stated you are a neophyte at python, how do you feel about VB?

Comment: Even more of a neophyte with VB, unfortunately.  I'd like to learn this stuff though.